# How to verify if VM has a set of extensions through Azure policy?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-policy

I'm trying to verify if a set of extensions are installed on VM, I have written the following policy but I think it is just evaluating the first extension or the policy is not behaving as desired. Can you help in solving this?

```js
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
        },
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/storageProfile.osDisk.osType",
          "equals": "Windows"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "auditIfNotExists",
      "details": {
        "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
        "existenceCondition": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/type",
              "equals": "NetworkWatcherAgentWindows"
            },
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/type",
              "equals": "ConfigurationforWindows"
            },
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/type",
              "equals": "DependencyAgentWindows"
            },
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/type",
              "equals": "VMAccessAgent"
            },
                        {
              "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/type",
              "equals": "AzureDiskEncryption"
            }
          ]        
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The extensions are listed as a resource similar to the type: "Microsoft.Compute/VirtualMachines", following is how an installed extension looks like in an ARM template

```js
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
    "apiVersion": "2023-03-01",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachines_ironmanjboxsit_name'), '/AzureNetworkWatcherExtension')]",
    "location": "eastasia",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', parameters('virtualMachines_ironmanjboxsit_name'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.NetworkWatcher",
        "type": "NetworkWatcherAgentWindows",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.4"
    }
}
```

Error/Problematic Behaviour:

The extensions I'm checking are a small set of what the VMs have. For example shown below, the VM also has AzureSecurityCenter extension on it along with the set of extensions I've mentioned in the policy.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> How to verify if VM has a set of extensions through Azure policy?

Here is an updated policy to audit `windows virtual machines` , if the specified extensions are not present on `VM`

```
{
    "mode": "All",
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
          },
               {
                  "anyOf":[
          {
            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/osProfile.windowsConfiguration",
            "exists": "true"
          },
          {
            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/storageProfile.osDisk.osType",
            "like": "Windows"
          }
                  ]
              }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "AuditIfNotExists",
        "details": {
          "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
          "existenceCondition": {
            "allOf": [
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/type",
                "equals": "NetworkWatcherAgentWindows"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/type",
                "equals": "ConfigurationforWindows"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/type",
                "equals": "DependencyAgentWindows"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/type",
                "equals": "VMAccessAgent"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/type",
                "equals": "AzureDiskEncryption"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "parameters": {}
  }
```

After assigning the policy to the scope, it will begin auditing the `Azure Windows virtual machines` as shown below.

> Note: The policy will take some time to audit the resources after it's assigned, so please wait for a while to see the results.

[image]

Comment: Hi Venkat, thanks for reply. But, I'm still facing the same difficulty. I get the resource is non-compliant even if the extensions exist on the VM. This is the reason I see in my Non-Compliance details.
Reason for non-compliance
Current value must be equal to the target value.
Field
Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/type
Path
properties.type
Current value
"WindowsAgent.AzureSecurityCenter"
Target value
"NetworkWatcherAgentWindows"

I feel that it is taking the order in which i specify the extensions in policy and checking them in the VM, rather than the whole set.